# Web Scraping with R using xpathSApply and trying to get only the links with "/overview"

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm doing a project for college that involves web scraping. I'm trying to get all the links of the players profiles in this website(http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/rankings/singles?rankDate=2015-11-02&rankRange=1-5001). I've tried to grab the links with the following code:

```
library(XML)
doc_parsed<-htmlTreeParse("ranking.html",useInternal =T)
root<-xmlRoot(doc_parsed)
hrefs1 = xpathSApply(root,fun=xmlGetAttr,"href",path='//a')
```

"ranking.html" is the saved link. When I run the code, it gives me a list with 6887 instead of the 5000 links of the players profiles.What should I do?

Comment: Refine your querying parameters. It sounds like you're getting all links instead of the 5000 you want. Somehow you need to figure out how to exclude the links outside of your search set.

Comment: Try `hrefs1<-unlist(hrefs1);hrefs1[grep("/en/players/.*/overview$",hrefs1)]`.

Comment: Your code extracts **all** the links of the page, try an xpath expression that narrows down to what you really want. Hint: look for unique classes in the document structure.

Comment: @nicola OP asks for a solution using XPath.

Comment: Thank you very much guys!It worked.I think I can use the solution with the unlist also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To narrow down to the links you want, you must include in your expression attibutes that are unique to the element you are after. The best and fastest way to go is using ids (which should be unique). Next best is using paths under elements with specific classes. For example:

```
hrefs1 <- xpathSApply(root,fun=xmlGetAttr, "href", path='//td[@class="player-cell"]/a')
```

By the way, the page you link to has at the moment exactly 2252 links, not 5000.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked. The thing is those 2252 links don't include the players that have the letter "T" among their position.

Comment: @AnnaB if the answer solved your problem could you mark it as the correct answer?